# ExpressJS: Inject Include into Jade using Javascript

Tags: express, pug

Say I have files such as follows

include/person.jade

```
.person
  .name= name
  .desc= desc
```

Now I want to have a button on my page that, when clicked, injects the previous into the document. I want this because I need to add people to the page. How would I go about doing this?

Should I just use an HTML file in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So similar to the previous example, I use express to host the Jade HTML for the person input in its own url something like this...

```
self.app.get('/person/:name/:desc',adddoc.person2);
```

Of course the person2 implementation is just a render of the Jade.

```
.person
  mixin personField(desc,name,valuefname,valuelname)
```

Then in my Javascript (using JQuery)

```
function stump(name, desc){
  $.get(
    "/person/"+desc+"/"+name,
    "{}",
    function(data) {
      var $parents = $( "#parents" );
      $parents.append($(data).filter('.person'));
    },
    "html"
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jade renders on server side. So you should call method with ajax that will return rendered html. Another option is to do this with JavaScript:

```
function addPerson(name, desc, parentId){
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'person';
    var nameContainer = document.createElement('div');
    nameContainer.className = 'name';
    nameContainer.innerHTML = name;
    container.appendChild(nameContainer);
    var descContainer = document.createElement('div');
    descContainer.className = 'desc';
    descContainer.innerHTML = desc;
    container.appendChild(descContainer);
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentId);
    parent.appendChild(container);
}
```

Jade:

```
#personContainer
input(onclick="addPerson('#{name}', '#{desc}', 'personContainer');", type="button")
```

Comment: I like your original idea (a server call for the rendered html) I will try it out. The second one I would probably just generate a html file and use that instead of using JS for the adding of indv. divs.

Comment: @Jackie You are right, it's becoming pretty big when doing with JS :)